# Loading An Image Onto Another Using Hover (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, hover

So as you can tell by the title, I'm trying to load an image above/onto another. It's kind of hard to use with this very amateur setup I have. Basically what I'm trying to do is load an image into the same position as the one that's being hovered. Hard to explain, but I think you might understand.

The code is here: [Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/Vfi00iNC)

What it currently does is create a map of sorts using images. Once hovered over, they dim out and display the realname of the image. What it doesn't do yet is load a new image above the currently hovered-over image if that makes sense. Hopefully someone can help. You can view its current status here: [Sinnoh.php](http://gogojjtech.com/misc/map/sinnoh.php)

(Scroll right to find some images)

Comment: Welcome. You should include the code in your question. Links can break.

Comment: I dont really understand what you are trying to make and what your question exactly is. Also instead of a pastebin of the code, a fiddle would be much better.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use Javascript for this? It is better done with CSS.

Comment: Well this is amateur hour, so I'm using whatever works. If you have a working CSS method, I'd gladly use it.

@Ozan - You see how the images fade when hovered? I'd like them to fade into another image. Like if it's named "route202.png", when you hover over it it'll apply the existing fades but fade into an image named "route202events.png"

I hope that clarifies a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the effect you want by placing the images on top of another, and adjusting their opacity values on hover. A simple transition will give it the fade in/out look you want.

```css
img {
  height: 600px;
  width: 200px;
}
.alt-img {
  opacity: 0;
}
.image-container:hover > .main-img {
  opacity: 0;
}
.image-container:hover > .alt-img {
  opacity: 1;
}
img {
  transition: 1s;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="main-img" src="http://gogojjtech.com/misc/map/route204.png" />
  <img class="alt-img" src="http://gogojjtech.com/misc/map/route205.png" />
</div>
```